# Match value to table with partial data and return value from another table with full data, otherwise null

Tags: sql

Table A is a table of all client accounts. Every client has a regular main account, but some clients have Special Category accounts in addition to their main account.

Table B associates the Special Category accounts with the main accounts. If a client does not have a Special Category account, they are not on Table B.

Table C is transactions coming from client accounts and the table I am working with.

```
Table A                Table B                Table C
+------+------------+  +------+------------+  +------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  ID  |    Name    |  |  ID  | Related_ID |  | c.ID |    c.ID    | b.related_ID |   a.Name   |
+------+------------+  +------+------------+  +------+------------+--------------+------------+
| 1001 | Alice      |  | 1002 |       1003 |  | 1001 | Alice      |            0 | 0          |
| 1002 | Bob        |  | 1004 |       1005 |  | 1002 | Bob        |         1003 | Bob EX     |
| 1003 | Bob EX     |  | 1004 |       1006 |  | 1004 | Charlie    |         1004 | Charlie EX |
| 1004 | Charlie    |  |      |            |  | 1005 | Charlie EX |            0 | 0          |
| 1005 | Charlie EX |  |      |            |  | 1006 | Charlie NA |            0 | 0          |
| 1006 | Charlie NA |  |      |            |  |      |            |              |            |
+------+------------+  +------+------------+  +------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

I would like Table C to have a column (a.Name) that returns the associated "EX" Special Category account if it exists, and otherwise be null it does not. I am struggling to match across two tables while still returning nulls when needed. I have listed Table columns "b.related_ID" and "a.Name" as an example of what I'm trying to get the table to look like. Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused.  It looks like that table already has `a.Name`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, the columns b.related_ID and a.Name are both examples of the data I want I want Table C to contain. I haven't managed to get them working out like that yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of **NULLIF** function

nulliff(a.Name,0)

Comment: I've experimented with this and haven't been able to figure something out that produces the results I need. I have got the table working where it has joined Table B successfully without omitting or duplicating lines, but I'm at a loss in how to match the related_ID from table B to the client name in Table A conditional on if it contains 'EX'.